# Passing a parameter in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am running this pig script from a grunt shell version pig 0.11.1

I have this data:

`Dec 2 15:13:52 mailserver1 sendmail[1882]: pB2KCqu1001882: from=<info@example.com>, size=9544, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201112022012.pB2KCqu1001882@mailserver1.example.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=relay1.example.com [10.0.20.6]`

Using this i am loading a relation:

`SRC = LOAD 'pg-log.txt'  USING PigStorage(' ') AS (
    month: chararray, 
    day: chararray, 
    time: chararray, 
    mailserver: chararray, 
    pid: chararray, 
    sendmailid: chararray, 
    src: chararray, 
    size: chararray, 
    classnumber: chararray, 
    nrcpts: chararray, 
    msgid: chararray, 
    proto: chararray,
    daemon: chararray,
    relay: chararray
);`

I am trying to get this below step working in the shell, where it appears to be taking a parameter $Year for the current year, and i have used this in the shell to initialize the year:

`%default YEAR date +%Y`;

but it does not work

`--T1 = FOREACH SRC GENERATE sendmailid, FORMAT('%s-%s-%s %s', $YEAR, month, day, time) as timestamp;`

So now i m trying to hardcode the year 2014 like below and i still get the error:

`T1 = FOREACH SRC GENERATE sendmailid, FORMAT('%s-%s-%s %s', 2014, month, day, time) as timestamp;`

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve FORMAT using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that FORMAT does not exists. Which is the case, there is no FORMAT function in PIG.

You can use CONCAT to do this. It's a bit ugly to put multiple CONCAT but you don't have the choice in pure PIG. Otherwise you can create an UDF fot this.